# Dispatcher script of network-manager no longer works

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

Soon after upgrading to networkmanager 0.9.8, I got the following message when it starts,

> Dispatcher failed: (32) Unit
>   dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service failed to load: No such
>   file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status
>   dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' for details.

And I noticed that all my dispatcher scripts (located in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`) are dead. The permission of each script is set to `700`, owned by root.

I've already run the name with `pkgfile` and `locate`, no output.

The file doesn't really exist, so where can I find it?

Comment: Did you try running the command: `systemctl status dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service`?

Comment: @slm Yep, the error message was `File Not Found`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upstream added a [separate](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=06a415d9ea2d3155ffa7bdfed999191f31f1f9ef) service for the dispatcher.
Try running:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

then

```
systemctl start NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

Since `dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service` is an alias, it should be working:

```
systemctl status dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2013-06-13 01:41:21 -0500; 3s ago
 Main PID: 1569 (nm-dispatcher.a)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
           └─1569 /usr/lib/networkmanager/nm-dispatcher.action
```

Comment: Having the `NetworkManager` service enabled solved the problem and the dispatcher scripts started working. Enabling it will automatically enable `NetworkManager-dispatcher`